# Group glossary entries

Tags: glossaries

I am currently writing the glossary for my Master Thesis and I would like to nest the 3 Kepler Laws under a generic "Kepler Laws" entry, but be able to call any independently.

An example of what I want:

```
entry 1
    blah, blah, blah
...
Kepler's Laws
   Kepler 1st law
       blah, blah, blah
   Kepler 2nd law
       blah, blah, blah
   Kepler 2nd law
       blah, blah, blah       
...
entry last
   blah, blah, blah
```

Any idea on how to do this?

I was thinking on something along the lines of:

```
\documentclass{ThesisClass}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\begin{document}

\newglossaryentry{Kepler1st}{name = Kepler\'{}s 1\textsuperscript{st} Law , description = First law,}
\newglossaryentry{Kepler2nd}{name = Kepler\'{}s 2\textsuperscript{nd} Law , description = second law,}
\newglossaryentry{Kepler3rd}{name = Kepler\'{}s 3\textsuperscript{rd} Law , description = third law,}
\newglossaryentry{KeplerLaws}{name = Kepler Laws of orbital movement , description = \glsentryfull{Kepler1st}\\\\glsentryfull{Kepler2nd}\\\\glsentryfull{Kepler3rd}\\ ,}

\printglossary[style=altlist,title=Nomenclature]

\makeglossaries

\end{document}
```

but for that does not work, I just get empty brackets under KeplerLaws. Worst case scenario, I will just create the 3 entries and that's it, but would prefer to nest them together.

Comment: Did you try `parent=KeplerLaws` for `Kepler1st`, `Kepler2nd` and `Kepler3rd`?

Comment: @ThorstenDonig: Tried it now, now I get empty brackets and underneath the description of the laws

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define a custom style to achieve what you want.

This is an example, based on the `index` default style. Note that it can be used only if you have one level's children.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{KeplerLaws}{name = {Kepler Laws of orbital movement}, description = {Kepler laws}}
\newglossaryentry{Kepler1st}{name = {Kepler\'{}s 1\textsuperscript{st} Law}, description = {First law}, parent = {KeplerLaws}}
\newglossaryentry{Kepler2nd}{name = {Kepler\'{}s 2\textsuperscript{nd} Law}, description = {Second law}, parent = {KeplerLaws}}
\newglossaryentry{Kepler3rd}{name = {Kepler\'{}s 3\textsuperscript{rd} Law}, description = {Third law}, parent = {KeplerLaws}}

\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
  \glossarystyle{index}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
  \item\glsentryitem{##1}\textbf{\glstarget{##1}{##2}}%
    \ifx\relax##4\relax
    \else
      \space(##4)%
    \fi
    \subitem##3\glspostdescription \space ##5}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{%
      \ifcase##1\relax
        % level 0
        \item
      \or
        % level 1
        \subitem
        \glssubentryitem{##2}%
      \else
        % all other levels
        \subsubitem
      \fi
      \textbf{\glstarget{##2}{##3}}%
      \ifx\relax##5\relax
      \else
        \space(##5)%
      \fi
      \subsubitem##4\glspostdescription\space ##6}%
}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\glsaddall
\printglossary[style=mystyle,title=Nomenclature]

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]